# R2dbc connection keeps on closing

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, r2dbc

This is my app.yml file for my gateway application

```yaml
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka/

spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true
      additional-exclude: static/**
    livereload:
      enabled: false

  jackson:
    serialization:
      indent-output: true

  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
      name: gateway
      profile: dev
      label: main     
liquibase:
  contexts: dev, faker
    url: jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x/db?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

  mail:
    host: localhost
    port: 25
    username: xxxxxx
    password: 'xxxxx'

  messages:
    cache-duration: PT1S 

  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:mysql://x.x.x.x/db?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: xxxxxxx
    password: 'xxxxx'**

  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: none
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  sleuth:
    async:
      enabled: false
    enabled: false
    sampler:
      probability: 1 # report 100% of traces

  zipkin:
    base-url: http://localhost:9411
    enabled: false
    locator:
      discovery:
        enabled: true

server:
  port: 8080

jhipster:
  gateway:
    rate-limiting:
      enabled: false
      limit: 100000
      duration-in-seconds: 3600
  registry:
    password: admin
  cors:
    allowed-origins: 'http://localhost:8100,https://localhost:8100,http://localhost:9000,https://localhost:9000,http://localhost:4200,https://localhost:4200'
    allowed-origin-patterns: 'https://*.githubpreview.dev'
    allowed-methods: '*'
    allowed-headers: '*'
    exposed-headers: 'Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-alert,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-error,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-params'
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
  security:
    authentication:
      jwt:
        base64-secret: NTI2MDA
        token-validity-in-seconds: 86400
        token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me: 2592000
```

The database is on siteground mysql. I have another microservice which gets connected to the database and it keeps the connection alive, but the above configuration connects to the siteground mysql and disconnects automatically and logs out of the application.
The error is "Connection closed by peer.".
Can you please provide your suggestions?